# Cannot add tensor to the batch: number of elements does not match. Shapes are: [tensor]: [585,1024,3], [batch]: [600,799,3]

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to train a model, at first I had dataset of 5000 images and training worked fine, Now I have added couple of more images and now my dataset contains 6,423‬ images. I am using python 3.6.1 on Ubuntu 18.04, my tensorflow version is 1.15 & numpy version is 1.16 (had same versions before and it worked fine).
Now when I use:

```
python model_main.py --logtostderr --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_resnet50_coco.config --model_dir=training
```

It starts settings up for couple of minutes and after these lines:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 0 into training/model.ckpt. 
I1123 10:26:21.548237 140482563244160 basic_session_run_hooks.py:606] Saving checkpoints for 0 into training/model.ckpt. 
2019-11-23 10:28:30.801453: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
```

I get following erros:

```
2019-11-23 10:08:38.843259: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1651] OP_REQUIRES failed at lookup_table_op.cc:788 : Not found: Resource localhost/_3_hash_table_2/N10tensorflow6lookup15LookupInterfaceE does not exist.               
2019-11-23 10:08:38.843323: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1651] OP_REQUIRES failed at lookup_table_op.cc:788 : Not found: Resource localhost/_1_hash_table_1/N10tensorflow6lookup15LookupInterfaceE does not exist.               
2019-11-23 10:08:38.843345: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1651] OP_REQUIRES failed at lookup_table_op.cc:788 : Not found: Resource localhost/_2_hash_table/N10tensorflow6lookup15LookupInterfaceE does not exist.                 
2019-11-23 10:08:38.851405: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1651] OP_REQUIRES failed at lookup_table_op.cc:788 : Not found: Resource localhost/_3_hash_table_2/N10tensorflow6lookup15LookupInterfaceE does not exist.               
2019-11-23 10:08:38.851488: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1651] OP_REQUIRES failed at lookup_table_op.cc:788 : Not found: Resource localhost/_1_hash_table_1/N10tensorflow6lookup15LookupInterfaceE does not exist.               
2019-11-23 10:08:38.851512: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1651] OP_REQUIRES failed at lookup_table_op.cc:788 : Not found: Resource localhost/_2_hash_table/N10tensorflow6lookup15LookupInterfaceE does not exist.                 
2019-11-23 10:08:38.851807: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1651] OP_REQUIRES failed at lookup_table_op.cc:788 : Not found: Resource localhost/_1_hash_table_1/N10tensorflow6lookup15LookupInterfaceE does not exist.               
2019-11-23 10:08:38.851848: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1651] OP_REQUIRES failed at lookup_table_op.cc:788 : Not found: Resource localhost/_2_hash_table/N10tensorflow6lookup15LookupInterfaceE does not exist.                 
2019-11-23 10:08:38.851899: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1651] OP_REQUIRES failed at lookup_table_op.cc:788 : Not found: Resource localhost/_3_hash_table_2/N10tensorflow6lookup15LookupInterfaceE does not exist.               
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                             
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1365, in _do_call                                                                                                                                 
 return fn(*args)                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1350, in _run_fn                                                                                                                                  
 target_list, run_metadata)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1443, in _call_tf_sessionrun                                                                                                                      
 run_metadata)                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.                                                                                                                                                           
(0) Invalid argument: Cannot add tensor to the batch: number of elements does not match. Shapes are: [tensor]: [585,1024,3], [batch]: [600,799,3]                                                                                                   
[[{{node IteratorGetNext}}]]                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[[ToAbsoluteCoordinates_118/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/data_0/_5709]]                                                                                                                                                                  
(1) Invalid argument: Cannot add tensor to the batch: number of elements does not match. Shapes are: [tensor]: [585,1024,3], [batch]: [600,799,3]                                                                                                   
[[{{node IteratorGetNext}}]]                                                                                                                                                                                                        
0 successful operations.                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
0 derived errors ignored.
```

and training stops.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example so we can try and help you faster and more accurately?

Comment: @ZaccharieRamzi I used https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/model_main.py on my dataset which is: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bCA0wRJw5YW9141mRJ2oG1MmiT7P7gPw

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the new images you've added have a resolution of 585x1024, which differs from the size that's expected by the model i.e. 600x799.

If so, then the solution is to resize these new images accordingly.

Comment: No all images have different resolution.

Comment: @DanialAhmed Then every image that has a different resolution will have to be resized (or cropped, padded, etc.) to 600x799.

Comment: I dont think so, because 1. When I first trained all the images had different sizes and everything worked easily.
2. I think the model I am using resizes the images itself. (It is stated in config file)
3. I just found out everytime I hit that error I get different size error like:
[tensor]: [600,900,3], [batch]: [576,1024,3]
[tensor]: [600,800,3], [batch]: [ 600,900,3]

Comment: Hmm.. the different sizes are probably due to a shuffle. Hard to tell what the problem is without seeing the code.

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/model_main.py

Comment: Can you try to resize all images to the same resolution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203052/discussion-between-danial-ahmed-and-eliadl).

Comment: @DanialAhmed If this answer solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution, please consider accepting it.

Comment: @DanialAhmed couple of things from my side, 1) cross-check the tensorflow version whether its gpu or cpu 2) try changing the --model_dir=training path may be its trying to append to the previous checkpoint file saved in the training director.

Answer (score 2):

If you need batch size > 1, you can resize the images to a uniform size with the right `image_resizer` in the config, one of the ones defined [in the image_resizer protobuf file](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/420a7253e034a12ae2208e6ec94d3e4936177a53/research/object_detection/protos/image_resizer.proto), which I assume is what is used to parse that part of the config.

For example (stolen from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34544#issuecomment-581446568)):

```
image_resizer {
  fixed_shape_resizer {
    height: 600
    width: 800
  }
}
```

This seems to fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the batch_size to 1 fixed this issue for me.

Comment: Of course, it did. You don't do batching anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In minibatch, all images must have the same size, so you must resize all photos to the same size or set the batch size to 1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just removed the data augmentation and it worked for me.
Also if you want you can try removing one after another data augmentations... but removing all just worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).